# How does one calculate the input impedance of a tube based preamp?

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube, preamp, input-impedance

I'm finding tons of information and equations on calculating this for solid state devices, but nothing for good old fashion particle accelerator based amplifiers :P

Currently I'm revamping the K270 guitar preamp to use components that are readily available. See the original design here: http://s13.postimg.org/patw5krxj/k270.png

This is my current progress: https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/852190-jan-6418-vaccum-tube-valve-preamp

Here is a snapshot at the time of writing this:
[image: JAN 6418 tube Preamp]

The problem I think I might run into is that my guitar's pizeo pickup requires a ridiculously high input impedance on the other side of the cable. I've been reading about jfet based piezo preamps and it's not uncommon to see people have 5 - 10 mohm input impedances on their piezo preamps.

1) How do I go about figuring out what the input impedance of my current circuit is?

2) How do I raise it if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input impedance is almost entirely set by R2/R1, so it's about 47K || 1M or about 47K.

You can increase R2, for example to 5M and leave out R1.

A tube behaves much like a JFET (which, in turn, is like a depletion-mode MOSFET with a diode from gate to source).

Comment: I'd suggest having a JFET preamp 'guitar side' of the cable. Having a very high input impedance on the amplifier side means there is a lot of opportunity for the cable to pick up noise. The added advantage is that the cable capacitance has much less effect on the sound - long cables will attenuate high frequencies which impact on the sound of your (assumed) acoustic guitar. A very simple JFET voltage-follower powered by a 9V battery will suffice. Example here: http://guitarnuts2.proboards.com/thread/3150. I've got a DIY one built into my (electric) guitar. Battery lasts for years.

Comment: @RJR The circuit is a preamp for a stomp box.

Comment: Hey one more dumb question,  what did you mean by your "||" operator? In computer science that means boolean OR

Comment: In this context it's short for parallel (parallel lines). For two resistors R1, R2  Rp = R1*R2/(R1+R2). For many resistors Rp = 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2 + ... + 1/Rn)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I know his circuit is. He mentions however he uses a piezo pickup - to get the best results out of that, a buffer at the 'guitar end' is best. This also means that the input impedance of the stomp box isn't really an issue anymore.

Comment: @RJR OK. Just wondering why you think a JFET amplifier with a 1.1M input impedance is better (loading-wise) than a tube amplifier with a 5M input impedance.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany because a high impedance at the end of a long guitar cable doesn't attenuate any noise picked up by the cable as well as a lower impedance would do. Furthermore, the buffer at the guitar side prevents the cable capacitance from causing a high-frequency roll off which is a particular issue for high output impedance piezo pickups. This issue is exacerbated by the fact that piezo's ore often used with (semi)acoustic guitars where the high frequencies are more important for the sound than for a standard electric guitar.